Get a total sum of the column whilst looping through rows



Patient
arrival datetime
depart datetime
Total in department




1
09/04/2024 23:00
10/04/2024 11:00



2
10/04/2024 07:42
10/04/2024 09:57



3
10/04/2024 09:15
10/04/2024 13:00



4
10/04/2024 08:56
10/04/2024 10:15



5
10/04/2024 05:00
10/04/2024 08:30



6
10/04/2024 06:15
10/04/2024 14:20



7
10/04/2024 01:29
10/04/2024 10:32



8
10/04/2024 08:22
10/04/2024 15:15




I'm completely lost. I thought I could create a loop if/elif func to go through each row and check if the arrival datetime was <= patient1's arrival datetime and the depart datetime was >= patient 1's arrival datetime then the column would give me a total for how many were in the department at patient1's arrival time and this loop would continue to go through each patient.

Here you can use a dataframe to store the data and loop through it to check the number of patients with satisfies given condition this is how you can do this ->
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Patient": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "arrival datetime": ['09/04/2024 23:00', '10/04/2024 07:42', '10/04/2024 
     09:15', '10/04/2024 08:56', '10/04/2024 05:00', '10/04/2024 06:15', 
    '10/04/2024 01:29', '10/04/2024 08:22'],
    "depart datetime": ['10/04/2024 11:00', '10/04/2024 09:57', '10/04/2024 
    13:00', '10/04/2024 10:15', '10/04/2024 08:30', '10/04/2024 14:20', 
   '10/04/2024 10:32', '10/04/2024 15:15']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Total in department'] = 0
df['arrival datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival datetime'])
df['depart datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['depart datetime'])

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    c = 0
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        if i != j and (df.loc[j, 'arrival datetime'] <= df.loc[i, 'arrival 
        datetime'] and df.loc[j, 'depart datetime'] >= df.loc[i, 'depart 
        datetime']):
            c += 1
    df.loc[i, 'Total in department'] = c

print(df)

You can use other data structures and can solve the problem like wise.
